# Waking Android over network

Tags: android, sdk

I'm a newbie when it comes to Android programming, but I've been doing a bit of digging in the SDK. I'm trying to create an application which allows me to wake the phone via a message sent over the network.

Ideally, I will have a java program on my computer which has a button I can push to wake the droid. I've read that a 3g socket can do this, but given that most providers use NAT, this doesn't seem like a good route.

I'd like to stay away from leaving the phone running with a wakelock, since that seems like it would kill the battery life. Is there any way to have the droid wake on an incoming network event? If not, what do you think the best way would be to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize C2DM messaging as well. You can initiate a wakelock when the C2DM message is received, do what you need and then release the lock.

[C2DM Documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)

Comment: This is nifty, didn't know about it. The OP would need to set up his own third-party server for this though, correct?

Comment: C2DM may not be reliable, though. I don't have any personal experience with it. I do know that Google states `C2DM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages.`

Comment: I use it and it's pretty reliable. It's what Google uses to talk with devices for their own services. Nothing is going to be 100% reliable because mobile network connectivity is so chaotic.

Comment: @koopaking3 Yes, he'd need a server to initiate the C2DM message to the device. Obviously what he does once he receives the C2DM is up to him.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of would be to create a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it for `SMS_RECIEVED` than send the device an SMS with some unique identifier of your choosing. The `BroadcastReceiver` will read incoming SMS and if it finds the unique identifier then it will wake lock the device and do any work (this you can handle in a `Service`). If you want to actually wake the device screen, that is a well-covered topic, but [here is one post on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215367/android-how-can-i-wake-up-the-phone-from-a-hard-sleep-to-take-a-picture). Once you've accomplished your work, you could then [delete the SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419184/how-to-delete-an-sms-from-the-inbox-in-android-programmatically) if you don't want it cluttering the inbox. Note that you would need the `READ_SMS` and `RECEIVE_SMS` permissions in your `Manifest`.

Sadly this isn't as elegant as a cool Wake on LAN type feature, but it should work nonetheless.

Let me know if you need an clarifying or examples.