# WakefulBroadcastReceiver not trigger when app is full closed (in android 6)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service, android-wake-lock

i want use GCM in my android project.

my codes is:

```
public class GcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
      GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));


    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
  }
}
```

and my InstentService is:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

  private Handler handler;

  public GcmMessageHandler() {
    super("GcmMessageHandler");
  }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
   }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();

  showToast();

  GcmReceiverOld.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
 }


  private void showToast()
  {
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
    });
  }

}
```

also i added Wale_Lock permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and added this line to manifest too

```
<receiver android:name=".gcm.GcmReceiver"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

                    <intent-filter >
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <category android:name="ir.test.gcmtester" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".gcm.GcmMessageHandler"
                 android:exported="false"
            />
```

but my problem is that  when the app full closed (in android 6) the GcmReceiver Class not trigger.

how can solve this problem?

Comment: GCM(https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is deprecated. Time for you to welcome FCM(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: @ChintanSoni Ok, but i think WakefulBroadcastReceiver  problem does not related to Gcm or Fcm

Comment: Try to check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736038/gcm-not-waking-up-device) which seems similar.