# How to invoke an android device from sleep?

Tags: android, sleep-mode, android-powermanager

In my application I have to enable the device 5 seconds after falling to sleepmode. I have tried different methods like

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                        "MyWakelockTag");
```

But its not working. Anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215367/android-how-can-i-wake-up-the-phone-from-a-hard-sleep-to-take-a-picture

Answer (score 1):

add these lines in your activity .

```
 getWindow().addFlags(
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```